# PHP array declare value from function of another value

Tags: php, arrays, declaration

does anybody have an idea how to declare value in array from function of another value inside this array?

```
$g = array(
    'v1' => "string",
    'v2' => md5(v1)
);
```

Comment: not like that no, but you could change how you define it https://3v4l.org/Tm7V6

Comment: is a good thing, just imagine `$g = [$g];`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function for that task

```
function whatever($value) {
    return [
        'v1' => $value,
        'v2' => md5($value)
    ];
}
```

Comment: thx! - so no other way without additional function?

Comment: others have demonstrated other ways... just pick one, or what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do it. You can get the `v1` value via `$g['v1']` once `$g` exists, but that is not true at the point of its definition. You might want:

```
$v1 = "string";
$g = array(
    'v1' => $v1,
    'v2' => md5($v1)
);
```

Comment: you could shorten `'v1' => $v1,` to `'v1' => $v1 = "string",`

Comment: @berend that's true, but I think it's less readable.

Comment: well, it useful, just don't wanna extra vars out of array, thx , i would voteup, but has no rep )